# Trouble floating items in CSS

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image]

So far, I have been able to do the following:
[image]

My problem are the following:

1- I cannot get the "Inicio" and "Productos" to be centered. I have tried margin: 0 auto, but had been futile since nothing moves. If i try margin-left I can move it. How can I 'auto' center this ?

2- Once "Inicio" and "Productos" have been centered. I would like to align with the image. Again I have tried to float left the image tage and float right the ul li , but I get something way off.

Can someone please help me figure out how to do this ?

Comment: Is there any HTML and CSS to go along with that image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the perfect solution you are looking for -

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/d6dtJ/25/

Comment: His first image has the text floating in the center; if you would check your own, you would see that it is not.  I've tested on chrome, firefox, and IE, same result in each.

Comment: Still does not work. Chrome on Windows 7. Resize your window and you'll see that the text does not stay centered.

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this i hope this will help you:-

**HTML**

```
    <div class="header">

<div class="logo"><img src="http://alansmoneyblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/google-logo.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="nav">
        <a>Link one</a> <a>Link two</a> <a>Link three</a>
        </div>
        <div class="mid">    
            <a href="#">Inicio</a>
            <a href="#">Productos</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.logo {
    float:left;
    width:128px;
    height:128px;

}
.nav {
    float:right;
    width:213px;
    height:128px;

}
.mid {
    background:red;
    height:128px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:213px;
    margin-left:128px;
    line-height:80px;
}
```

see the demo:-
http://jsfiddle.net/d6dtJ/23/

Comment: This answer does not do what the OP wants it to do.

Comment: @ShailenderArora .. it does not do **exactly** what the OP wants.  They didn't ask for a table-like box, they just wanted their text centered.

Answer (score 0):

[This should do what you want it to](http://jsfiddle.net/sQ63V/3/), I've tried to keep it simple.

Comment: @Deadalus its not proper method in which u gave the solution see if i have added a border in your code check whts happening now:- http://jsfiddle.net/sQ63V/30/

Comment: @ShailenderArora The code looks fine.  You're just singling out different elements..  I can see no reason for this, the code does what the OP wants, it shouldn't be a downvote just because **you don't like it**

Comment: @ShailenderArora How about you define `proper method`?

Comment: firstly i didn't downvote you and i am not saying i dont like it your method the thing is every person has their own method...so we should adopt the exact proper method for our results thats it....

Comment: @ShailenderArora I take that bit back then, however that still leaves my second question unanswered; how do you define 'proper method'?

Comment: You should never define 'proper method' by your own reasoning, but something more concrete.. say, another's reasoning that is more accepted as standard by multiple parties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that it would look like the yellow image, the try this:
**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <p><a href="#">Avuda</a> <a href="#">Acceso</a> <a href="#">Registrarse</a></p>
    <img src="http://m.onkey.org/images/rails-logo.jpg?1314545460" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="center"><a href="#">Inicoi</a> <a href="#">Productos</a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.main {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
.center {
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 10px 0 25px;
}
img {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
p {
    text-align:right;}
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/unrbd/